# Removing numbers from a given string

Tags: string, list, function, numeric, cpu-word

I am trying to get rid of any numbers in a string.

However, when I run my program the number is removed, but other parts of the string are removed as well.

```
string = 'My name is Anish, & I am 22 years old! The wall is blue, and the floor is orange. The weather is great, but it is raining?'

def num_remover(words):
    t = words.split()
    d = [e for e in t if e.isalpha()]
    a = " ".join(d)
    return a

print(bluh_remover(string))
```

output:

> My name is I am 22 years The wall is and the floor is The weather is but it is

Comment: It would be nice to add information in which programming language it is, add it also to labels.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Minor nitpick, but `bluh_remover` isn't in the code--you probably meant `num_remover`. Can you show your actual output to contrast with your expected output? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NEVERMIND: I figured it out.

Apart from calling out the wrong function haha. I was able to think simply and just replace the number with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing because you have split the string, therefore, the word Anish will come as 'Anish,' which is not string because of special character.
string = 'My name is Anish, & I am 22 years old! The wall is blue, and the floor is orange. The weather is great, but it is raining?'

```
def num_remover(words):
    new = ''
    temp = ''
    for i in words:
       if i.isdigit():
           new = new + temp
           temp = ''
       else:
           temp = temp + i
    return new + temp
print(num_remover(string))
```

Output:

```
My name is Anish, & I am  years old! The wall is blue, and the floor is orange. The weather is great, but it is raining?
```

Answer (score 0):

For any string longer than 10 words, a simple Replace loop would be faster. In VBA, for example:

```
Dim StrTxt As String, i As Long
StrTxt = "My name is Anish, & I am 22 years old! The wall is blue, and the floor is orange. The weather is great, but it is raining?"
For i = 0 To 9
  StrTxt = Replace(StrTxt, i, "")
Next
MsgBox StrTxt
```